# requirejs window not defined

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm getting this error when the optimizer is launched by grunt
(I'm using yeoman backbone-generator )

> > Running "requirejs:dist" (requirejs) task
> >      Error: ReferenceError: window is not defined

I'm using requirejs and the plugin i18n.
This is my main.js

```
    require.config({
    //locale: "en",
    shim: {
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: [
                'underscore',
                'jquery'
            ],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'jquery-notify': {
            deps: [
                'jquery'
            ]
        },
        swiper: {
            deps: [
                'jquery'
            ],
            exports: 'Swiper'
        },
        bstrapcollapse: {
            deps: [
            'jquery',
            'bstraptransition'
            ],
            exports: 'collapse',
        }
    },
    paths: {
        jquery: '../bower_components/jquery/jquery',
        backbone: '../bower_components/backbone-amd/backbone',
        underscore: '../bower_components/underscore-amd/underscore',

        i18n: '../bower_components/requirejs-i18n/i18n',

        'backbone.marionette': '../bower_components/backbone.marionette/lib/core/amd/backbone.marionette',
        'backbone.wreqr': '../bower_components/backbone.wreqr/lib/amd/backbone.wreqr',
        'backbone.babysitter': '../bower_components/backbone.babysitter/lib/amd/backbone.babysitter',
        'jquery-ui': '../bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui',
        loglevel: '../bower_components/loglevel/dist/loglevel.min',
        moment: '../bower_components/moment/moment',
        alertify: '../bower_components/alertify/alertify',
        swiper: '../bower_components/swiper/dist/idangerous.swiper-2.0.min',
        fastclick: '../bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick',
        bstrapcollapse: '../bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/bootstrap-collapse',
        bstraptransition: '../bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/bootstrap-transition',

        'requirejs-text': '../bower_components/requirejs-text/text',
        async: '../bower_components/requirejs-plugins/src/async',
    },
    config: {
        i18n: {
            locale: JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('settings')).language || 'en',
        }
    }
});
```

I need to change language based on user input that's why i need to fetch localStorage and set the locale in the config.

There's a solution for this?
Thank you.

Comment: For obvious reasons, you can't run that in Grunt.

Comment: Actually when on grunt server it all works fine. It's only the grunt build process ( that call the requirejs optimizer ) that got the problem

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done much in the region of runtime javascript, but I know that many of the libraries you know and are used to in browsers (document object model's "getElementById", local storage) are not available in runtimes like Grunt or Rhino. Your use of localStorage in that settings file appears to be the issue.

Instead, you need to make use of whatever API is given to you. For instance, a quick search found some Grunt examples where they read/write to a file on the filesystem: http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile

Obviously, this would be impossible in a browser, as browsers don't let you access files; but you may as well take advantage of it in Grunt. You can also feature-detect which mode you're in with clauses like this:

```
if (window) {
  ...
}
else if (grunt) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that worked for me :

```
config: {
    i18n: {
        locale: (function(){              
            try{
                return localStorage.getItem('locale') || 'en' ;
            }catch(ex){
                return 'en';
            }
        })()
    }
}
```

But still not convinced by this trick. Maybe someone else has a better idea ?